# Getting Jest global setup and global teardown to work in a typescript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, jestjs, typeorm

I want to run a function that opens db connection before running tests (global setup) and another function that closes db connection after tests are run (global tear down). Currently I have the following config:

package.json:

```
//...
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "globalSetup": "./src/jest/globalSetUp.ts",
    "globalTeardown": "./src/jest/globalTearDown.ts",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "ts"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    }
  }
```

and my globalSetUp.ts:

```
import { initDB } from "../dbUtils"

module.exports = async () => {
  await initDB();
}
```

globalTearDown.ts:

```
import { closeDB } from "../dbUtils"

module.exports = async () => {
  await closeDB();
}
```

But when I run my tests I get 2 main errors.

```
Determining test suites to run.../home/me/Projects/.../Table1.ts:1
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany, Index, PrimaryColumn, ColumnType, ColumnOptions } from "typeorm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

and

> CannotExecuteNotConnectedError: Cannot execute operation on "default"
> connection because connection is not yet established.

This means that the global setup function was not run. Note I am using typeORM.

How do i properly set things up so this will work?

Edit:
My initDB function:

```
export async function initDB() {
  console.log("inside intiDB");

  await createConnection().then(async connection => {
    console.log("connected to db");
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

when I run tests I see `inside initDB` but I don't see `connected to db`. I think createConnection() looks through my entities dir and the issue rised when it hits Table1.ts. Then it complains that

> import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany, Index,
> PrimaryColumn, ColumnType, ColumnOptions } from "typeorm";
> ^^^^^^
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> ```

If I remove globalSetup and globalTearDown and instead just use a beforeAll and afterAll inside my test file then everything works.

Comment: Could you describe what commands you use to run the tests?

Answer (score 2):

The typescript environment is not yet defined when *globalSetup* and *globalTeardown* are run, which is why jest is failing.

A workaround is to create the environment manually by requiring *ts-node* in those files.

Here is an example:

```
require('ts-node/register');

const setup = (): void => {
  // whatever you need to set up globally
};

export default setup;
```

Comment: So i added `require('ts-node/register');` to both globalSetup.ts and globalTeardown.ts. But when I try to run it I now get `TSError: src/jest/globalTearDown.ts:26:111 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ label: number; sent: () => any; trys: any[];
 ops: any[]; }'.

26                     if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }`

Comment: So I guess TS is now working and you have a typing error. Hard to debug without seeing the whole file though.

Comment: The code its referring to isn't mine though. My file isn't even 26 lines long.

Comment: Try to run your function like so: `const setup = (): void => { require('../dbUtils').initDB(); };`

Comment: @LTM I believe you can do `require("ts-node").register({transpileOnly: true})`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `require` statements instead of `import` statements in your teardown and setup files like so:

```js
//globalTearDown.ts

const { initDB } = require("../dbUtils"); //<--- use require instead of import

module.exports = async () => {
  await initDB();
}
```

Do the same with your teardown file.

Comment: That didn't fix it. I put console.logs in globalTearDown.ts and it does print something so the file gets run fine. Edited my post