# ts-node transpiles createConnection in typeorm to (0, typeorm_1.createConnection)

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm, transpiler, ts-node

I was facing the same issue as [Getting Jest global setup and global teardown to work in a typescript project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64508664/getting-jest-global-setup-and-global-teardown-to-work-in-a-typescript-project), so I went with the solution provided in the answer and wrote 'require(ts-node/register)' at the top of my global setup file.
But, during transpilation, the following error occurs:
[image: Screenshot of error].

My global setup file looks like,

```js
require('ts-node/register');
import { Connection } from "typeorm";
import { closeTestingConnection, createTestingConnection, dropTestingDatabases, runMigrationsOnDatabase } from "./utils/util";

/**
 * Creates database connection before running any test case
 */
const globalSetup = async () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let testConnection: Connection | undefined;
        try {
            testConnection = await createTestingConnection();
            await runMigrationsOnDatabase(testConnection);
            resolve(true);
        } catch (error) {
            if(testConnection) {
                await dropTestingDatabases(testConnection);
                await closeTestingConnection(testConnection);
            }
            reject(error);
        }
    })
}

export default globalSetup;
```

which uses a util function 'createTestingConnection',

```js
export function getDBConfig(envName?: string): ConnectionOptions {
    let file: string;
    if (envName) {
        file = __dirname + "/../../test/settings/ormconfig." + envName + ".ts";
    } else {
        file = __dirname + "/../../test/settings/ormconfig.local.ts";
    }
    try {
        return require(file);
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error("Unable to locate ++ DB Config.");
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a testing connections based on the configuration in the ormconfig.json
 * and given options that can override some of its configuration for the test-specific use case.
 */
export async function createTestingConnection(): Promise<Connection> {
    const testEnvName: string = process.env.TEST_ENV || "local";
    return createConnection(getDBConfig(testEnvName));
}
```

Comment: This question relies on outlinks and images to make sense. Please supply all relevant information **as text** in the body of your question.

Comment: StackOverflow is not letting me embed images to the post so, I would have to use a link to image that has the error snippet. Anyway, I added the global setup file as text.

Comment: I have added the image inline... however, the error messages that it contains are the "gold" when it comes to other people finding this question when they encounter the same problem as you. This is why images should only be a supplement rather than a vital component of the question.

Comment: Okay. Understood. But can you help me with the problem?